# a random spanning tree intersect with a set is sum of Bernolli

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, graph-theory, random-variables

Consider a set of edges of an arbitrary connected graph.

Now pick a random spanning tree of graph. Prove that the distribution of the size of intersection is equal to sum of some independent Bernoulli RV.

I tried for some small cases but I couldn't find any pattern.

Comment: What a scary nickname :P

Comment: @hypergeometric So, It's better to answer me! XD